# How can i order by for multiple queries combination

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following query :

```
 with t1 as (select PROCESS_NAME, row_number() over (order by PROCESS_NAME ) rn from #tempDIM_INVENTRUST_PROCESS_MST ),   
      t2 as (select *, row_number() over (order by PROCESS_NAME ) rn from #tempDIM_INVENTRUST_SUB_PROCESS_MST),
      t3 as (select *, row_number() over (order by USER_NAME ) rn from #tempIvenTrust_V_USER_SKILL_DETAILS ),
      t4 as (select *, row_number() over (order by USER_NAME ) rn from #tempIvenTrust_V_USER_SKILL_DETAILS_2),
      t5 as (select *, row_number() over (order by VCHAR_CLIENT ) rn from #tempCLIENT_INFO_FPY), --clientName  
      t6 as (select *, row_number() over (order by VCHAR_PRODUCTGROUP ) rn from #tempPRODUCT_GROUP_INFO_FPY_GROUP_NAME), --groupname  
      t7 as (select *, row_number() over (order by VCHAR_PROJECT ) rn from #tempPRODUCT_GROUP_INFO_FPY_PROJECT_NAME) --projectname  


      select t1.PROCESS_NAME as PROCESS_NAME_1,'' as col1,t2.PROCESS_NAME,t2.SUB_PROCESS_NAME,'' as col2,t3.USER_NAME,
      t3.PROCESS_NAME as PROCESS_NAME_2 ,''  as col3,t4.USER_NAME as Reviewer,t4.Process_Name as PROCESS_NAME_3
      ,t5.VCHAR_CLIENT,t6.VCHAR_PRODUCTGROUP ,t7.VCHAR_PROJECT
--    into #temp
   from 
      t1 full outer join t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
      full outer join
      t3 on t2.rn = t3.rn
      full outer join
      t4 on t3.rn = t4.rn
      full outer join
      t5 on t4.rn = t5.rn
      full outer join
      t6 on t5.rn = t6.rn
      full outer join
      t7 on t6.rn = t7.rn
      order by 
      t2.PROCESS_NAME desc,
      t3.USER_NAME desc,
      t4.USER_NAME desc,
      t5.VCHAR_CLIENT desc,
      t6.VCHAR_PRODUCTGROUP desc,
      t7.VCHAR_PROJECT desc
```

This gives me following result as :

```
 Col1       Col2  Col3  Col4         Col5

 NULL        1     2    NULL         NULL

 somevalue   2     3    NULL         NULL

 somevalue   2     3    somevalue    NULL

 somevalue   NULL  NULL    NULL    somevalue
```

As shown in result NULLs are comming in between the result.
I dont want NULL to appear first.

I want it as:

```
 Col1       Col2  Col3  Col4         Col5

 somevalue   1     2    NULL         somevalue

 somevalue   2     3    NULL         NULL

 somevalue   2     3    NULL         NULL

 NULL      NULL  NULL    NULL      NULL
```

I tried with diffrent combinations of order by.

But failed to do so.

Please help me.

Comment: You can only re-order whole rows...

Comment: @jarlh  when I order by col1 , col5 gets spoiled and vice a versa

Comment: Yes, that's how it works.

Comment: Do you want to order by column wise separately or you want the rows with maximum values in each column to be on top ?

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed YES , exactly...

Comment: then it wont work in a single query, create a temp table & fill it up as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't (yet?) support `NULLS FIRST`/`NULLS LAST` in the `ORDER BY`.  But this is easily done with an additional key:

```
order by (case when t2.PROCESS_NAME is not null then 1 else 2 end),
         t2.PROCESS_NAME desc,
         t3.USER_NAME desc,
         t4.USER_NAME desc,
         t5.VCHAR_CLIENT desc,
         t6.VCHAR_PRODUCTGROUP desc,
         t7.VCHAR_PROJECT desc
```

Comment: OP is trying to order each column separately.

Comment: @DSLR . . . This is the `ORDER BY` from the query in your question.  The only difference is that the `NULL` values for the first key are put at the end rather than at the beginning.  This appears to be what you want (based on the query "col1" = "PROCESS_NAME").